# Calling function error: explicit instance of the class

Tags: asp.net, sql, ajax, jquery

I am trying to save data to database with webmethod, jeditable and SqlDataSource tool. But getting some error with function call. i try to find on google but not able to remove or understand bug [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406555/cannot-refer-to-instance-member-of-a-class-from-within-a-shared-method-witout-an) , [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsswe45.aspx). In code view it is pointing to SqlDataSource1 as error.

**This is the error :** Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

default.aspx.vb page code

```
< WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function HelloWorld(var2 As String, var3 As String)
    Dim tempData As String = 0

    If var2 = "edit_main_contents" Then
        tempData = var3
        dbValue(var2, var3)
    ElseIf var2 = "edit_second_contents" Then
        tempData = var3

    Else
        Return 0

    End If
    Return tempData
End Function

Public Shared Function dbValue(data_ID As String, data_value As String)

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("datatext").DefaultValue = data_value
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("myID").DefaultValue = data_ID
    SqlDataSource1.Insert()
    Return "job done"

End Function
```

default.aspx page code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.editable_textile').editable(function (value, settings) {
            var returnValue;
            var textboxID = $(this).attr('id');
            var returnValue = oGod(textboxID, value);
            return (returnValue);
        }
        , {
            width: '350',
            submit: 'Save Changes',
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            onBlur: 'ignore'
        });
    });
    function oGod(textboxID, NewValue) {
        var resultData;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "default.aspx/HelloWorld",
            data: '{ "var2" : "' + textboxID + '", "var3" : "' + NewValue + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (msj) {
                resultData = msj.d;                    
                return resultData;
            },
            error: function (e) {
                resultData = "error";
                return resultData;
            }             

        });
        return resultData;
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot called a `none-shared method` in a `shared method` without creating an instance of it.

So you need to assign `Shared` keyword to your `dbValue()`, but you will not be able to call page controls (in this case `SqlDataSource`) in `Shared` methods!

If you want to return a DataTable and say populate a control, you can return a list of object and bind on success of ajax call.

In your case I see you are doing an insert only, so you can run a stored procedure or inline sql from your `dbValue()` function.

An Example :

```
string stmt = "INSERT INTO Your Table";//you can paste the SqlDataSource query here

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(smt, _connection);
//your parameters
cmd.Parameters.Add("@datatext", SqlDbType.Int).Value = data_value; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = data_ID;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: if i put "Public Shared Function dbValue" then it shows error with SqlDataSource1's. if i put only "function dbValue" then it not showing error on SqlDataSource1, But it shows error on dbValue(var2, var3)

Comment: thank you for your advice. I am not a programmer person to code like stored procedure or inline sql. it will be highly appreciated if you refer me some links to do that, i am also googling too.

Comment: @JasbirBhinder see the example(I haven't tested it so it may have syntax error)...